# How to select in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Now I have such controller method:

```
     def modelv
    @model = Model.find(:all, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man]}) 
    @ct = CountryDesignation.find(:all, :conditions => { :CDS_ID => "110000002"})
    @destext = DesText.find(:all, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => "388555"})
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @model }
    end
  end
```

but I want that it looks like this:

```
 def modelv
    @model = Model.find(:all, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man]}) 
    @ct = CountryDesignation.find(:all, :conditions => { :CDS_ID => @model.MOD_CDS_ID})
    @destext = DesText.find(:all, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => @ct.CDS_TEX_ID})
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @model }
    end
  end
```

But my model structure is that:

COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS has_many MODELS

DES_TEXTS has_many COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS

MANUFACTURERS has_many MODELS

So if I select @model - it is array, if  select @ct - it's array (for every model), if select @destext - it's array. How to correctly select this. And how to display this in view? now my view looks like this:

```
%p#notice= notice

%h3
  - @model.each do |model| 
    %tr
      %p
        mod_id
        %td= model.MOD_ID
        name
        -#%td= model.country_designations.des_texts.TEX_TEXT
      = link_to 'Show model', model
= link_to 'Back', manufacturers_path
```

And I wont to look like this:

```
%p#notice= notice

%h3
  - @model.each do |model| 
    %tr
      %p
        mod_id
        %td= model.MOD_ID
        name
        %td= @destext.TEX_TEXT
      = link_to 'Show model', model

= link_to 'Back', manufacturers_path
```

Answer (score 0):

If MODELS belongs_to COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS and COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS belongs_to DES_TEXTS then the find should only return one result.  Then you don't need find(:all, ...), you need

```
@model = Model.find(:first, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man]}) 
@ct = CountryDesignation.find(:first, :conditions => { :CDS_ID => "110000002"})
@destext = DesText.find(:first, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => "388555"})
```

Comment: "110000002" but i need field! And when i select model it is many! Its array!

Comment: If you need many, then find :all, but since you will get many back, it has to be an array.  If there are many returned from a find, you need to deal with an array of those results.  How else could it work?

Comment: I asked how to get it with array in view! and how change this piece :CDS_ID => "110000002" to :CDS_ID => @model.FIELD . But you are writting the same, but another words, could you help me, or only empty answer?

Comment: Then I really don't understand what you are asking.  I can't help you, if I don't understand your question.

Comment: what I was looking is models = Model.all(:conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man] })
@ct = CountryDesignation.all(:conditions => { :CDS_ID => @models.map(&:cds_id) })                it's mapping. But now I have another problem how can i format this it in view, so that every model displays it ct and destext fields? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272366/how-to-correctly-view-such-in-rails          Also is it better way to get this fields? for example model.coutry_designation.des_text.Field???

Comment: You did not have any view information in your question and your question is getting into design.  This forum does not work on designing your app for you and it expects a certain amount of work on your part.  We're here for you if you get stuck not understanding how ruby (or something else) works.  Your question here should have asked, "I get an array from Model, how to I get the array of CountryDesignation values?" but you asked "I get an array!", so I explained why you would be getting an array from find :all, in case that had you stuck.

Comment: stop! help me please with selecting such things! becouse in every tutorial is only 2 deep, for example @post.comments.each, but i have 3 levels! model.country_des.des_text.each, that what i need you help me. But i have another structure, not model has many countrydes, but forwards, destexts has countrys. and country has models! that is my question!

Comment: See, table MODELS has field MOD_CDS_ID, with this field I go to table COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS and it's field CDS_ID = MOD_CDS_ID (from MODELS table), than from this table I select field CDS_TEX_ID and go with this id to table DES_TEXTS it's field TEX_ID must be equal from previous table CDS_TEX_ID, and fetch field TEX_TEXT !!! And this field in my iteration @model.each do.... i must display for every model. Now its clear for you?