# How to correctly view such in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view

I have selected for every model it's data from another table using this in controller:

```
  def modelv
    @model = Model.find(:all, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:man]}) 
    @ct1 = CountryDesignation.all(:conditions => { :CDS_ID => @model.map(&:MOD_CDS_ID)})
    @ct = @ct1.uniq{|hh| hh.CDS_ID}
    @destext = DesText.find(:all, :conditions => { :TEX_ID => @ct.map(&:CDS_TEX_ID)})
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @model }
    end
  end
```

sorry for dirty code.

and my view

```
%table   %tr
    %th Mfa id
    %th Год начала выпуска
    %th Год завершения выпуска
  - @model.each do |model| 
    %tr
      %td= model.MOD_CDS_ID
      %td= link_to model.MOD_ID, model
      %td= link_to model.MOD_PCON_START, model
      -if model.MOD_PCON_END.blank?
        %td= link_to "По настоящее время", model
      -else
        %td= link_to model.MOD_PCON_END, model
      -#%td= model.country_designations.des_texts.TEX_TEXT
      -#= link_to 'Show model', model   %br %table   %tr
  - @destext.each do |t|
    %tr
      %td= t.TEX_ID
      %td= t.TEX_TEXT
  - @ct.each do |ct|
    %tr
      %td= ct.CDS_ID
      %td= ct.CDS_TEX_ID
```

But how to display for every model its t.TEX_TEXT and ct.CDS_TEX_ID, not in another loop, but in same table, in column? And moreover, my method is fetching data, but when I select data, when ct.CDS_TEX_ID is same for some more than one entry, @destext is grouping, and i fetch only one instance, for example

```
cds_id    cds_tex_id
110007626 420077
110007627 420077
```

and as result i get from @destext only one row. Help me please. It's non-standart db

> See, table MODELS has field MOD_CDS_ID, with this field I go to table COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS and it's field CDS_ID = MOD_CDS_ID (from MODELS table), than from this table I select field CDS_TEX_ID and go with this id to table DES_TEXTS it's field TEX_ID must be equal from previous table CDS_TEX_ID, and fetch field TEX_TEXT !!! And this field in my iteration @model.each do.... i must display for every model